# EJS Header/Footer not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, ejs

I'm working a basic todo list app using EJS. I'm getting this when running. I'd like to be able to run app.js with the header and footer EJS. Except it does not reconize the header and I'm sure it's the right syntax. Any tips or pointers to help me out?

P.S All my EJS files are located in the views folder

`Error: /Users/brenner/dev/web-dev-course/todolist-v1/views/list.ejs:2`

```
Could not find the include file " header"
    1| 
 >> 2| <%- include(" header" ) -%>
    3| 
    4|   <div class="box" id="heading">
    5|     <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
```

list.ejs :

```
  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">


    <% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
    <form action="/delete" method="post">
      <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <p><%=  newListItems[i].name  %></p>
      </div>
    </form>

    <% }) %>


    <% for (let i=0; i<newListItems.length; i++) { %>
      <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <p><%=  newListItems[i].name  %></p>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="listName" value="<%= listTitle %>"></input>
      <% } %>

      <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
      </form>
  </div>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

Header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"
  </head>
  <body>
```

Footer

````
<footer>
  Copyright 2020 Brenner Inc
</footer>

</html> ```
````

Comment: It says *Could not find the include file " header"*, so do you have a file called ```" header.ejs"``` (including the space at the front of the file name that you typed)?

Comment: @Quentin yes I have a header.ejs inside my views folder

Comment: And the filename starts with a space? Really?

Comment: @Quentin I'm not even adding the space... the auto format when I save does it

Comment: So fix your autoformatter!

Answer (score 1):

Try this call `<%- include('header') %>`. There is a bug with an extra space: `( 'header')`. Should be `('header')`

Answer (score 0):

create new directory (folder) inside "views" and put your header and footer file in it. and use

<%- include('partials/header') %>

```
<!-- your HTML code -->
```

<%- include('partials/footer') %>